# Internet Explorer doesn't redirect on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, yii2

I send ajax post request to server and respond with 302 redirect. All browsers follow this redirect except IE. I see in Network tab of IE dev tools that 302 response is received.

Also jQuery `.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {...})` callback return the following data in `jqXHR`:
`[object Object]{readyState: 0, status: 0, statusText: "error"}`

Which is strange because status is not 302.

Testing on IE 11.

EDIT
Response headers:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date    Tue, 27 Oct 2015 12:24:47 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.7-1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.6.7-1
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
X-Redirect  http://mysiteaddress.com/somepage/
Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=123; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length  0
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=96
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

EDIT2 I guess it's Yii2 framework-specific bug. Client script must handle `X-REDIRECT` header, but can't do this in IE. See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#redirect()-detail.

Comment: are you saying the fail callback is executed in IE ?

Comment: @Michael fail callback executed in all browsers. I think it's ok for redirect response.

Comment: can you post the redirect line you are returning in the header from your backend code?

Comment: @Michael, added to my question.

Comment: thanks. What is the url you are requesting with ajax?

Comment: @Michael why is it important? Somethin like this: `Request POST /some/script/index.php?r=ajax/action&param=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: 302 should supply a `location:` header, `X-Redirect:` is a custom header ...

Comment: @AlexK. when I set Location header it redirects ajax request to this page and loads all page content via ajax. Browser is not redirected to this new page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Yii2 specific bug/behaviour when you use yii\web\Response::redirect() method.
Everything seem to work fine if you return code 200 instead of proper redirection code 302.

See:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#redirect()-detail and
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9670

Comment: Still happening in 2020 but it works well because FF doesn't like having location.reload after ajax of posted data, so PRG pattern is the best solution and submitting a server 'ok' response seems to satisfy IE for this.